# Internal Direct Sum Question

Tags: linear-algebra

Showing R_2[t] (real polynomials of degree 2 or less) is the internal direct sum of {polynomials that vanish at t=0} and {span of t^2+2t+1}. I've shown how both of those sets are in fact subspaces of V=R2[t]. I'm trying to show that, for any arbitrary v=at^2+bt+c, it can be broken down into those two subspaces. I can't seem to manipulate the a,b, and c coefficients properly to show this. Something like v=at^2+bt+c=xt^2+yt+s(t^2+2t+1), but of course with the coefficients cancelling out properly on both sides of the equal sign. Any help is appreciated.

Comment: Are these polynomials with real coefficients?

Comment: If you have $at^2+bt+c$, you know that one factor must be $c(t^2+2t+1)$. What is the other factor? Is this factorisation unique?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

$at^2 + bt+c = (a-2c)t^2 + (b-2c)t +c(t^2+2t+1)$

Comment: Thanks a lot Prahlad. I see how this was derived just going through it in my head.

Comment: I believe this is a mistake. $a t^2 + b t + c = (a-c) t^2 + (b-2c) t + c (t^2 + 2t + 1)$